# iptables (NAT/PAT) setup for SSH & Samba

Tags: ssh, samba, iptables

I need to access a Linux box via SSH & Samba that is hidden/connected behind another one.

Setup :-

```
  
 A        switch    B         C
|----|    |---|    |----|    |----|
|eth0|----|   |----|eth0|    |    |
|----|    |---|    |eth1|----|eth1|
                   |----|    |----|
```

Eg, SSH/Samba from A to C

How does one go about this?
I was thinking that it cannot be done via IP alone? Or can it?

Could B say "hi on eth0, if your looking for 192.168.0.2, its here on eth1"?
Is this NAT?
This is a large private network, so what about if another PC has that IP?!

More likely it would be PAT?
A would say "hi 192.168.109.15:1234"
B would say "hi on eth0, traffic for port 1234 goes on here eth1"
How could that be done?

And would the SSH/Samba demons see the correct packet header info and work??

IP info :-

```
A - eth0 - 192.168.109.2
B - eth0 - B1 = 192.168.109.15 B2 = 172.24.40.130
  - eth1 - 192.168.0.1
C - eth1 - 192.168.0.2
```

A, B & C are RHEL (RedHat)
But Windows computers can be connected to the switch.
I configured the 192.168.0.* IPs, they are changeable.

---

Update after response from [Eddie](https://serverfault.com/questions/137000/iptables-nat-pat-setup-for-ssh-samba/137046#137046)

Few problems *(and Machines' B IP is different!)*

From A :-
`ssh 172.24.40.130` works ok, (can get to B2)
but `ssh 172.24.40.130 -p 2022 -vv` times out with :-

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.24.40.130 [172.24.40.130] port 2022.
...wait ages...
debug1: connect to address 172.24.40.130 port 2022: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 172.24.40.130 port 2022: Connection timed out
```

From B2 :-

```
$ service iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.2         tcp dpt:22

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2022 to:192.168.0.2:22

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

And ssh from B2 to C works fine :-

```
$ ssh 192.168.0.2
```

Route info :-

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.24.40.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
default         172.24.40.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

$ ip route  
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1
172.24.40.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.24.40.130
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link
default via 172.24.40.1 dev eth0
```

So I just dont know why the port forward doesnt work from A to B2?

Answer (score 1):

**For SSH**

On B:

```
#Arbitrary port
SOME_PORT=2022
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $SOME_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:22
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
#On a machine type A:
ssh -p $SOME_PORT
```

**For Samba**

Is it possible to mount C shares via nfs on B then setup samba on B?  If not, then you can redirect the samba ports:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport –dports 139,445 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp –dport 137:138 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

If samba is already running on B, then you could bind an additional IP address on B and forward to C (you could do this for ssh also to keep port 22. Be wary of services starting on the 0.0.0.0 address):

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.109.16 netmask 255.255.255.0

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.15.109.16 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.15.109.16 -p tcp -m multiport –dports 139,445 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.15.109.16 -p udp –dport 137:138 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

**EDIT**
I see you're still having problems; make sure that:

- Machine B has ip forwarding enabled :
  echo 1 >
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
- Machine C has a route back to the
  user via machine B.  If not, then set
  a masquerade rule on machine B :

  iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE

tcpdump can be useful to troubleshoot.  On machine B:

```
#capture and display packets heading to 192.168.0.2
tcpdump -i any -p tcp ip host 192.168.0.2 and port 22
```

Comment: small note just for ref : "ssh -p $SOME_PORT" => "ssh <B_ip_addr> -p $SOME_PORT"

Answer (score 1):

What you have termed PAT would work. You will need to have iptables running(or some customizable firewall). Then run the following commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -p DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 135:139 -p DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 445 -p DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
service iptables save
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

In the file /etc/sysctl.conf, change the line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

to

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Well, assuming that the switch always routes traffic to machine B, you can just do:

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
```

That should tell machine B that, if traffic comes in for the 192.168.0.0/24, send it out eth1.

That should work, and it's a bit easier than setting up a NAT. You'll need to make sure the switch knows to route traffic for 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.109.15 (Eth 0 on B).

@Ian: Routing isn't necessarily easy, but it's not that hard either. That's what routers do. Assuming your switch is just a switch, with no routing capability, you can't use it to set the route, but you have to have a router somewhere or your network is purely a local LAN with no internet access.

Check your machines, and find out where the default gateway is (on the linux boxes you can just type `route` with no arguments. Your default gateway route is the one that looks like:

```
default         192.168.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

That's your "core" router. that's the machine all the machines look to to figure out where machines on other subnets are. That's where you need to add a route pointing to the B machine as the gateway router for the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.

If you can give me some information on your router, I can tell you how to add that route.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I have simplified the network diagram, there are many machines like A, and some have many hops, but they can all access B-eth0 ok. As you state, getting traffic for 192.168.0.0/24 to KNOW to goto 192.168.109.15 would be hard?! So this makes this solution not workable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, excellent idea, and your right, that would work! IF... I was allowed to change the main router. But I am within a company network, and thus cannot do that! (I have had them set routing for my subnet, 192.168.109.0/24 -> 172.24.150.50, but I was pushing my luck getting that!) Any anyway, I am actually after a different solution for transparency and portability. So again, many thanks...